# Is there an official book about the different races and classes of the realm of Faerun?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, races, class

Is there an official book made by wizards of the coast that discusses the different races and classes of the realm of Faerun?

Answer (score 8):

The book you're looking for is the **Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide** (ISBN 978-0786965809).

Comment: Also the Players Handbook. And Xanathar's Guide to Everything. And Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes.

Comment: Forgotten Realms is the default setting for 5e, so it's safe to say that all of the books thus far discuss it.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog Not for the three core books. See [Is Forgotten Realms the default setting in 5e?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45584)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I posit that "not exclusively" isn't the same as "Not at all," but I otherwise concede the point.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog The “not exclusively” is being cute; it’s not at all, unless all possible imaginable settings being technically part of the default setting makes FR in particular somehow *the* default. :)